# How do you unlock/find costumes in Marvel: Ultimate Alliance 2

Tags: marvel-ultimate-alliance

How do you find or unlock alternate costumes for the characters? I have been playing through missions and have found upgrades and other unlockables but not any costumes but each character has the option when selecting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[SOURCE](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?p=2349376)***

All of the costumes can be unlocked by defeating 50 enemies (except Juggernaut who requires 300), though some require a certain alignment in the Civil War. All of the 50 enemies killed can be done in missions, via replay or in the combat simulations. Be sure to unlock every costume you can for your alignment on your first playthrough before starting your second. So for instance, after Act 1 if you choose Pro-Reg, get all of Iron Man, Mr. Fantastic, etc. before starting a new playthrough or you'll miss your chance to unlock them. Characters marked as Neutral can be done regardless of which side you choose, but still have to be done after Act 1.

**Pro-Registration Campaign**

- Deadpool
- Iron Man
- Mr. Fantastic
- Ms. Marvel
- Songbird
- Spider-Man

**Anti-Registration Campaign**

- Captain America
- Human Torch
- Invisible Woman
- Iron Fist
- Luke Cage
- Wolverine

**Neutral**

(can be done in either campaign)

- Daredevil
- Gambit
- Green Goblin
- Hulk
- Iceman
- Jean Grey
- Juggernaut
- Penance
- Storm
- Thing
- Thor
- Venom

Comment: Weird, I am pretty sure I have defeated way over 50 foes with Carnage and still no costume but there  has go to be a way of checking each character's kill count, but I haven't found that feature if there is one.

Comment: I believe you also have to be in control of the character that actually does the killing blow. I'm not 100% sure on that as it's been a while since I've played it.